# Make <li> items side by side and at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my list items side by side (horizontal). HOWEVER, I can only use html (no css).

Also, I am trying to make the li items move below the image (to the bottom of the page).

I have tried various different attributes and have done lots of searching, but nothing seems to do the trick.

```
<div style="background-color:black; margin-top:0px">
    <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/mercury2.html"><img src="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/images/Mercury1.jpg" style="float:left; margin-right:10px" height="400" width="400"></a>
    <p style="color:brown">Mercury is the smallest planet, and it's closest to the Sun of the eight planets in the Solar System. It has an orbital period of about 88 Earth days.</p>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div>
    <ul style="list-style:none">
        <li style="text-align:left"><a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/museum.html"><p style="color:blue">Previous room</p></a>
        <li style="text-align:right"><a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/venus1.html"><p style="color:blue">Next room</p></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are able to use inline styling, the CSS limitation is not that relevant.

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline-block` in the style attribute of your `<li>`s?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.

Comment: Since `<p>` are block style by default, I think that takes precedence. Can you try `inline-block` on the `<li>`s or use `inline` on the `<p>`s (along with `inline` on the `<li>`s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to make my list items side by side (horizontal).

Use `style="display: inline-block"` on the `li` elements.

> Also, I am trying to make the li items move below the image (to the bottom of the page).

Use `style="position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%;"` on the containing `div` element

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpo8vzdm/))

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
    <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li style="text-align:left; display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/museum.html">
                <p style="color:blue">Previous room</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li style="text-align:right; display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/venus1.html">
                <p style="color:blue">Next room</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked to make the li elements inline, but they are now crammed to the left of the page. How can I make the second li element hug the right side of the page?

Comment: Ok, I just floated the second li to the right, and now it looks good. Though, I am still curious, now the two li elements follow me as I scroll through the page, is this due to fixing the position?

Comment: Yes, you can use `position: absolute` if you want it to stay in one spot

Answer (score 2):

Use this style attribute for li element:

```
style="text-align:left;float:left;display:inline-block;"
```

You need to add:

float:left and display:inline-block

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<li style="text-align:left">
```

to

```
<li style="float:left">
```

to make the list items side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/3v8j0xf1/ ?

changed

```
<div style="background-color:black; margin-top:0px">...
```

to

```
<div style="background-color:black; margin-top:0px; float: left;">...
```

and li's

```
<li style="text-align:left">...
<li style="text-align:right">...
```

to

```
<li style="text-align:left; float: left;">...
<li style="text-align:right; float: left; margin-left: 20px;">
```

Comment: what's the reason of down rate?

Answer (score 0):

You cant make list items display side by side without css, but I see you're using inline css so assuming you mean you cant use external css.

this is my suggestion to both parts of your question, I also removed the p tags inside the li's as you shouldnt use them there.

```
<div style="background-color:black; margin-top:0px">
    <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/mercury2.html"><img src="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/images/Mercury1.jpg" style="float:left; margin-right:10px" height="400" width="400"></a>
    <p style="color:brown">Mercury is the smallest planet, and it's closest to the Sun of the eight planets in the Solar System. It has an orbital period of about 88 Earth days.</p>
</div>


<div style="clear:both">
    <ul style="list-style:none;padding:0">
        <li style="text-align:left;display:inline-block;width:50%;color:blue"><a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/museum.html">Previous room</a>
        <li style="text-align:right;display:inline-block;width:50%;color:blue"><a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/venus1.html">Next room</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `bottom:0; position:absolute` to wrapper `div`. Apart from it you will need to add `float:left;` to li.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:black; margin-top:0px">
    <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/mercury2.html"><img src="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/images/Mercury1.jpg" style="float:left; margin-right:10px" height="400" width="400"></a>
    <p style="color:brown">Mercury is the smallest planet, and it's closest to the Sun of the eight planets in the Solar System. It has an orbital period of about 88 Earth days.</p>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div style="bottom: 0px; position: absolute;">
    <ul style="list-style:none">
        <li style="text-align: right; float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
            <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/museum.html"><p style="color:blue">Previous room</p></a>
        </li>
        <li style="text-align: right; float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
            <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/venus1.html"><p style="color:blue">Next room</p></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You may think of removing the 
 tags.

You may also see [FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/npralhad/3masxfkL/) - https://jsfiddle.net/npralhad/3masxfkL/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the exact look you're looking for, but along the lines of what others are saying, I'd use inline-block on the list items.  I also added a % width to the image to give you a little responsiveness and force the line break.

```
<div style="background-color:black; margin-top:0px">
  <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/mercury2.html"><img src="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/images/Mercury1.jpg" alt="" style="float:left; margin-right:10px; height:auto; width:100%;" /></a>
  <p style="color:brown">Mercury is the smallest planet, and it's closest to the Sun of the eight planets in the Solar System. It has an orbital period of about 88 Earth days.</p>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="position:relative; bottom:0;">
  <ul style="list-style:none">
    <li style="display:inline-block;"><a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/museum.html"><p style="margin:0; color:blue">Previous room</p></a>
    <li style="display:inline-block; margin-left:3em;"><a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/venus1.html"><p style="color:blue">Next room</p></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```