# make one <li> appear at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, electron

I've got a vertical menu in which i want the last li tag to appear at the bottom of the page. I've tried a few things suggested like vertical-align bottom but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my HTML.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
caption {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
}

#leftmenu {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>SquashBug</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="intro">
    <div id="content">
      <p1>Content</p1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="leftmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#Start">Issue Finder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#First">System Information</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Second">Running Processes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Third">Anti-Virus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Fourth">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I'm basically trying to do is if you click this link https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_navbar.asp and look under right align links you will see a horizontal menu with About forced to go to the right. I want to have that in the vertical menu with the last link being at the bottom of the page. I'm creating an electron app if that is of any useful information.

Comment: give us you HTML to see the structure of your page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957108/make-li-items-side-by-side-and-at-bottom-of-page

Comment: Ok can I not edit this post?

Comment: Made the edits to show full html and css

Comment: Flex will help you here, look up the align property.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
caption {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e0fcff;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#leftmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}

ul {}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.Btm {
  position: fixed;
  Bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

.Btm a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p1>Content</p1>
</div>

<ul id="leftmenu">
  <li><a class="active" href="#Start">Issue Finder</a></li>
  <li><a href="#First">System Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Second">Running Processes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Third">Anti-Virus</a></li>
  <li class="Btm"><a href="#Fourth">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: On my electron app all the menu items are gone except for about which stays to the top. I think the #leftmenu css is causing the issue.

Comment: further inspection on the last class with just bottom:0; and position: fixed the link goes straight to the top and shows over issue finder link

Comment: @TimMarshall I updated my answer.

Comment: @TimMarshall You wanted like this? I edited my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
.nav-list {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.last {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Because there is no way for the CSS see which `<li>` tag is last, you will have to manually set it by using `<li class=“last”>`. Make sure that your navigation bar is is a `<ul class=“nav-list”>` tag with a set height (aka, not `auto`. I recommend `height: 100%`)

Comment: Found a cheap and easy solution, since the electron app window is going to be static, I made the .last class margin-top: 369px. It works. Thanks for your help guys.